# Error in starting wso2 server : org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error! Subquery returns more than 1 row at

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

Error in WSO2 api manger while trying to connect an external database in a system acessing while vpn.

```
    Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error! Subquery returns more than 1 row
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.addAuthorizationForRole(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1079)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.authorizeRole(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:527)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Subquery returns more than 1 row
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:970)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1020)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor33.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager.addAuthorizationForRole(JDBCAuthorizationManager.java:1025)
    ... 38 more
```

Comment: to which database you are trying to connect ? Also can you post your database configuration that you have in datasource .xml file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subquery returns more than 1 row occured due to an faulty data in one of the tables. Solved this issue updating the table with clearing and updating the data inserted.